# c# hyperlink pulling page data

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, charts

I'm not really sure how best to dull this down so that you understand what I am asking but I will give this a shot!!!

Basically I have designed a set of .NET charts that show my users important information. The design requires that the charts be of a set size with a 'view larger' hyperlink that then pulls up a large copy of the chart in a lightbox.

Where I have come stuck is actually displaying these charts in the light box through the hyperlink.

I'm wanting to know how I would write a query string that would link the chart data do the hyperlink??? Any help would be great!

Code I have tried

```
HL_chart1.NavigateUrl = CH_BrandVisits.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres your problem, right there; its not going to work I can tell you that much